# How to search using Sphinx from JSON formatted File?

Tags: java, php, python, sphinx

I have well formatted JSON File.
From Sphinx search ,i first convert it into sphinx xml formatted File.
Then using xml pipe on new generated xml file ,i do Sphinx Search.
Is there any direct way to search on json with out converting into specific xml file?

Answer (score 3):

No sphinx cant read json directly. Converting to xml seems like the easiest way.

Note you dont have to convert to a file, sphinx can read the output of a script. So the script could just be reading the josn file, and outputing xml directly. No intermediate file actully required.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx has only 2 types of data source they are sql data source and xmlpipe datasource. At the moment you cant directly search json files

One solution that I can think off is to store the json data in a database and then use sql data source. Just be creative when storing the json data and when indexing it.